# Laravel Vapor - The command "npm ci && npm run dev && rm -rf node_modules" failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I've been working on a project for a few years and now it's finally time to deploy my application to the internet! I've been building my app on homestead, and I've been following the laravel vapor tutorial on youtube. I follow all the instructions, however when I get to the deployment part (typing "vapor deploy staging") it returns the following error:

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Screenshot 3:

[image]

Comment: Well, it literally says "The `npm ci` can only install with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later generate a package-json.lock file, then try again."... Do you have a `package-lock.json`? Official doc about [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci)

Comment: I don't think so. What's that?

Comment: That file (`package-lock.json`) is generated when you run `npm install`, so it locks the dependencies. You have to run `npm install` locally and commit the file to your git repository, so it locks the dependencies to the same versions for everyone. It is exactly the same as `compose.lock` but for Javascript